# Perl function to replace general nested fraction expressions in Latex

Tags: regex, linux, perl, unix

I have a perl script that I use in association with a bash script to replace characters and general nested fractions in a file with some Latex code snippet. The part of the perl script that governs fraction replacement is given by the following function:

```
sub process_latex {
    my ($latex) = @_;
    1 while $latex =~ s{
        \\frac
        \{
            ((?:[^{}]|(?R))*) # numerator (match balanced braces)
        \}
        \{
            ((?:[^{}]|(?R))*) # denominator (match balanced braces)
        \}
    }{
        my ($numerator, $denominator) = ($1, $2);
        $numerator = process_latex($numerator);
        $denominator = process_latex($denominator);
        "($numerator)/($denominator)";
    }gex;
    return $latex;
}
```

This script can successfully handle nested fraction expressions that don't happen to have any other Latex commands in any of their arguments, at any depth. For example. using this script, I can replace the expressions

```
\frac{\frac{x11}{x12} x2}{\frac{y1}{y2 \frac{y31}{y32}} y4}
\frac{\frac{a1}{a2} \frac{b1}{b2}}{\frac{c1}{c2} \frac{d1}{d2}}
```

with

```
((x11)/(x12) x2)/((y1)/(y2 (y31)/(y32)) y4)
((a1)/(a2) (b1)/(b2))/((c1)/(c2) (d1)/(d2))
```

But it does not work for expressions like

```
\frac{ \frac{1\frac{2}{3}}{4} a{} }{ b{} }
\frac{\epsilon+\gamma}{2^{-4\epsilon}}
\frac{\frac{1}{2} \textbf{a}}{b \textit{c}}
```

for which, I should get

```
((1(2)/(3))/(4) a{} )/( b{} )
(\epsilon+\gamma)/(2^{-4\epsilon})
((1)/(2) \textbf{a})/(b \textit{c})
```

but instead, end up getting

```
\frac{ (1(2)/(3))/(4) a{} }{ b{} }
\frac{\epsilon+\gamma}{2^{-4\epsilon}}
\frac{(1)/(2) \textbf{a}}{b \textit{c}}
```

I can use some help in modifying the perl function, so as to have the correct replacement for Latex fraction expressions that may contain nested or chained pairs of braces in their arguments, such as `\frac{a{}{}}{b}` or `\frac{a}{b{{}}}`, where `a` and `b` are some generic Latex commands.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `(?R)` recurses the whole pattern, and it needs the `\frac` text to start matching. Once you replace some `\frac`s inside the string, you may no longer find a match.

So, a potential fix is to only recurse the substring between curly brackets only:

```perl
sub process_latex {
    my ($latex) = @_;
    1 while $latex =~ s{
        \\frac
        (\{
            ([^{}]*(?:(?1)[^{}]*)*) # numerator (match balanced braces)
        \})
        (\{
            ([^{}]*(?:(?3)[^{}]*)*) # denominator (match balanced braces)
        \})
    }{
        my ($numerator, $denominator) = ($2, $4);
        $numerator = process_latex($numerator);
        $denominator = process_latex($denominator);
        "($numerator)/($denominator)";
    }gex;
    return $latex;
}
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/3r6xLn).

Here, `((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)` parts are replaced with `([^{}]*(?:(?1)[^{}]*)*)` and `([^{}]*(?:(?3)[^{}]*)*)` to only recurse the necessary pattern parts, and the replacement is adjusted accordingly (`($1, $2)` => `($2, $4)`).